# Wordpress site structure

Tags: php, wordpress

Have not been working with wordpress for a couple of years now and want to get some ideas/input on how to structure a project I'm about to set up. The idea is that it should work like this:

The page is simply a small search engine where you can search for posts in categories.
I have a start page. The start page is basically an input field where you can search. I also have this menu that lists 3 items, those items are names on categories you can search in. How would i do to set a predefined category to search in depending on what you choose in the menu?

so for example. if you click "cats" in the menu and then start typing in the input field and then submit i want the search to be limited to that category "cats".

Also. it would be good i you could route the different categories.

Like:

```
www.site.com/cats - contains a search field, you search only in the category cats.
www.site.com/dogs - contains a search field, you search only in the category dogs.
www.site.com/birds - contains a search field, you search only in the category birds.
```

How would i set up this in the best way?

Create 3 pages, one for each search field?
Just list categories in one index.php and do all in there?

Ideas?

Comment: You're asking for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic for this site.

Comment: code would work as well. Actuallly,it would be better.